# First ng-view template's controller not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My landing page component's controller doesn't retrieve any data when the app initially loads or when I reload from the landing page. I keep getting `undefined` for my variables when I have verified there is data.

If I click on the `#/index` link, the data loads fine and my variable logs to the console. Any idea why this happens to only the initial load of the webpage and when I reload it on the landing?

Edit: Added the `appUser` value that I am trying to log along with the app's main controller. Essentially, I run a service via `appStore` to retrieve user details. I then set my `appUser` value. I have confirmed the `appStore` service works.

It seems like the `MainLandingCtrl` runs before the `AppCtrl`

app.module.js:

```
angular.module('dup', ['ngRoute', 'mainLanding', 'unauthorized']);
```

app.value.js

```
angular.module('dup')
    .value('appUser', {

        fup: undefined
});
```

app.controller.js

```
angular.module('dup')
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['appStore', 'appUser', '$log',  function(appStore, appUser, $log) {

        var rcAppTemp = this;

        // User authorization
        appStore.authorizedUser()
            .then(function(response) {
                rcAppTemp.userDetails = response.data;
                appUser.fup = rcAppTemp.userDetails.fup;

            }, function(error) {
                $log.log('error');
            });

    }]);
```

app.config.js:

```
angular.module('dup')
.config(['$routeProvider',  function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // Main page
        .when('/', {
            template: '<main-landing></main-landing>'
        })
        .when('/unauthorized', {
            template: '<unauthorized></unauthorized>'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

main-landing.controller.js:

```
angular.module('mainLanding')
    .controller('MainLandingCtrl', ['appUser', '$log', function(appUser, $log) {

        var mn = this;
        mn.fup = appUser.fup;

        $log.log(mn.fup);
}]);
```

main-landing.component.js

```
angular.module('mainLanding')
.component('mainLanding', {
    bindings: {
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/main-landing/main-landing.template.html',
    controller: 'MainLandingCtrl'
});
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="dup">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
        <!-- navigation bar (excluded for brevity) -->
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

main-landing.template.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 medium-offset-4 large-4 large-offset-4 columns">
        <div title="Home">
            <h5>Dup</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/index"><strong>Index</strong></a></li>
                <li ng-show="$ctrl.fup><a href="#/unauthorized"><strong>Trouble</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think still some essential context is missing, such as for instance how you bind the main controller to the main-landing directive? and what exactly you are trying to log.

Comment: @KeesvanLierop I'll add that now...

Comment: @KeesvanLierop Added the details....